# Dividir un arreglo n veces y esas n veces convertirlos a arreglos

Tags: java

Tengo una duda y quisiera ver si alguien puede ayudarme, necesito que un arreglo ingresado por un usuario dividirlo en n veces, esas n veces que se dividió
sean nuevos arreglos.
¿Cómo podría hacerlo en java?

El usuario ingresa los valores, los almaceno y en cuanto se va dividir

```
System.out.print("\n\nNuevos estados convertidos a array: \n");
 for(int c=0;c<array_r.size();c++){
     System.out.print(array_r.get(c)+" ");
 }
```

luego imprime esto `q1 q2 0 q2 0 0`

donde necesito quede en estado nuevo1=`q1 q2 0` y nuevo2=`q2 0 0`

Comment: El arreglo que quieres dividir en otros arreglos es "q1 q1 0 q1 0 0"? y quieres generar 2 "q1 q1 0" y "q2 0 0"? o como? puedes explicarlo un poco mejor, con gusto e ayudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la explicación que has dado de tu programa, puedo ofrecerte dos soluciones *(he dado por hecho que usas ArrayList por el método **get()** y **size()** que usas)*.

**1ª.** Se crea un ArrayList *aux* en el que se almacenan los datos antiguos de *array*; se añade el nuevo estado y se muestra cuáles son nuevos y cuáles no.

```
public void addEstados(String est, int posicion) {

    ArrayList<String>aux = new ArrayList<String>();

    //rellena el contenido de aux con el contenido de array
    for(int i=0; i<array.size(); i++) {
        aux.add(array.get(i));          
    }

    array.add(posicion, est);

    System.out.print("\n\nNuevos estados convertidos a array: \n");
    for(int i=0; i<aux.size(); i++) {

        if(aux.get(i)==array.get(i)) {
            System.out.println("Nuevo1: "+array.get(i));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Nuevo2: "+array.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

**2ª.** Se usa un booleano; la secuencia es la misma que el anterior código, solo que se mostrará el contenido mientras sean similares. En caso que se añada un nuevo estado, muestra el contenido a partir de la posición del estado añadido. Este se adapta mucho más a la salida que quieres.

```
public void addEstados(String est, int posicion) {

boolean iguales=true;
ArrayList<String>aux = new ArrayList<String>();

//rellena el contenido de aux con el contenido de array
for(int i=0; i<array.size(); i++) {
    aux.add(array.get(i));          
}

array.add(posicion, est);

System.out.print("\n\nNuevos estados convertidos a array: \n");
//muestra el contenido que ambos tienen similar hasta que no se cumpla dicha condicion
System.out.print("Nuevo1: ");
for(int i=0; i<aux.size() && iguales==true; i++) {

    if(aux.get(i)==array.get(i)) {
        System.out.print(array.get(i)+" ");
        iguales=true;
    } else {
        iguales=false;
    }
}

//muestra el contenido a partir del nuevo estado
System.out.print("\nNuevo2: ");
for(int i=posicion; i<array.size();i++) {
    System.out.print(array.get(i).toString()+" ");
}
```

}

Antes de realizar esto, he rellenado *array* de ceros para que funcione; si quieres añadir una nueva posición que no está creada, dará error.

```
public Estados() {
        setArray(new ArrayList<String>());
        array.add("q1");
        array.add("q2");

        for(int rellenar=array.size(); rellenar<6; rellenar++) {
            array.add(rellenar,"0");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es dividir un array generando una salida de (array/n) arrays.

La clase [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) tiene muchos métodos útiles para manejar y ordenar arrays. Uno de los métodos es *copyOfRange*, el cual devuelve un array con los elementos desde n hasta k.

Tendrás que hacer un pequeño método que calcule los elementos de cada array de salida, teniendo en cuenta muy especialmente el resto de la división (% ó módulo), en caso de que la división no sea exacta.

Un saludo